# Finding overlapping sequence with regular expressions with Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract numbers and both previous and following characters (excluding digits and whitespaces) of a string. The expected return of the function is a list of tuples, with each tuple having the shape:

```
(previous_sequence, number, next_sequence)
```

For example:

```
string = '200gr T34S'
my_func(string)
>>[('', '200', 'gr'), ('T', '34', 'S')]
```

My first iteration was to use:

```
def my_func(string):
    res_obj = re.findall(r'([^\d\s]+)?(\d+)([^\d\s]+)?', string)
```

But this function doesn't do what I expect when I pass a string like `'2AB3'` I would like to output `[('','2','AB'), ('AB','3','')]` and instead, it is showing `[('','2','AB'), ('','3','')]`, because 'AB' is part of the previous output.

How could I fix this?

Comment: You may check another answer and feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no overlapping numbers, a single trailing
assertion should be all you need.

Something like `([^\d\s]+)?(\d+)(?=([^\d\s]+)?)`

This `([^\d\s]*)(\d+)(?=([^\d\s]*))` if you care about
the difference between NULL and the empty string.

Comment: In yor last sentence, do you mean "if you *don't* care"?

Comment: @NiklasB. - That's a tough question, I don't know, could go either way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifier `+` and `?` you can simply use `*` :

```
>>> re.findall(r'([^\d\s]*)(\d+)([^\d\s]*)',string)
[('', '200', 'gr'), ('T', '34', 'S')]
```

But if you mean to match the overlapped strings you can use a positive look ahead to fine all the overlapped matches :

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?=([^\d\s]*)(\d+)([^\d\s]*))','2AB3')
[('', '2', 'AB'), ('AB', '3', ''), ('B', '3', ''), ('', '3', '')]
```

Comment: seems to be working, thank you! The secret is the *?

Comment: Kasramvd actually I would need the output for '2AB3' to be [('','2','AB'), ('AB','3','')], without all the other overlapped matches. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be using regex and functions!

```
import re

#'200gr T34S'  '2AB3'


def s(x):
    tmp=[]
    d = re.split(r'\s+|(\d+)',x)
    d = ['' if v is None else v for v in d] #remove None
    t_ = [i for i in d if len(i)>0]
    digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    nms = [i for i in t_ if i[0] in digits]
    for i in nms:       
        if d.index(i)==0:
            tmp.append(('',i,d[d.index(i)+1]))
        elif d.index(i)==len(d):
            tmp.append((d[d.index(i)-1],i,''))
        else:
            tmp.append((d[d.index(i)-1],i,d[d.index(i)+1]))
    return tmp

print s('2AB3')
```

Prints-

```
[('', '2', 'AB'), ('AB', '3', '')]
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to do the job, but a single line like `re.findall(r'([^\d\s]+)?(\d+)(?=([^\d\s]+)?)',string) ` also and is cleaner I think.